# Whats the idiom for "you do not discuss your problem with the source of it"?

Tags: idiom-requests

I am forgetting the idiom thats essentially means that you shouldn't look for solutions from a person who is the cause of your problems.

Thanks

Comment: Is there one..?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is, as a slang maybe, if not as a common idiom

Comment: In 60 years of listening, I've never heard of such a thing. Perhaps there should be, but what makes you think there is?

Answer (score 0):

Distant Yiddish saying:

**When you send a cat for butter, you'll eat dry bread.**

= Choose your agents of change wisely.

Answer (score 0):

These idioms are not an exact fit, but means the same thing and may serve your purpose.

- Don't ask the devil for directions.
- Don't deal with the devil
- Adding fuel to the fire
- Making matters worse
- Baiting the wolf
- Tempting fate